# Flutter dispose not working when im logout firebase auth

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When i try `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();` pages dispose not working and give error

> Listen for Query(users/N08gk97AZxblQ6dfghAHQ67ZxIJkI19z2) failed:
>   Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient
>   permissions., cause=null}

I have like that so much error when call signOut, i have `StreamSubscription` and `StreamController` i added dispose close and cancel, i think dispose doesn't work when I switch pages

Does dispose need to work when I leave the page?

if it doesn't work, why won't it work?

Does AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin cause this?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: you need to post minimal code and stackTrace atleast

Answer (score 0):

```
PERMISSION_DENIED
```

this specific to your backend Firebase, if it was working before but not now then you have exhausted your day limit of signing in/out, or else you have not set up your firebase correctly, check the google-services.json and your app signature

Comment: Does AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin cause this?

Comment: need more details I've gone through this in firebase..can you post more stack , after this error if you restart the app does it ask you to sign in or does the user stays signed in?